# mapping redux state array value without checking for its length

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

hi guys so whenever I map an array that comes from redux I always have to check for its length else it would be undefined , the code is like this (i just write the relivant part of the code) :

Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  senders: [],
  
};
```

action

```
const res = await api.get(`/users/senders`);
      dispatch({
        type: GET_SENDERS,
        payload: res.data.senders,
      });
```

Component

```
     useEffect(() => {
    getSenders(searchedVal);
  }, [senders.length, searchedVal, senders.senderDeleted]);


 {senders.senders.length > 0 &&
                width < 991 &&
                senders.senders.map((el) => {
                  return ( .....etc
```

why is it undefined if yo u dont check for the array length , is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: Try making like this senders?.senders?.map

Comment: that is still checking for the array, the question is if you do a api request in a React component (not using redux) you dont need to check senders.length, the array will already have value when the component is rendered, but its not the same case for redux, or im doing something wrong ..